# Referencing shared publishing profile in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

In my repository I have the next structure:

```
Common
    \PublishProfiles
        \Profile.pubxml
Solution1
    \WebProject1
Solution2
    \WebProject2
```

I want to share Profile.pubxml between two projects. Everything seems to work fine when I use msbuild with PublishProfileRootFolder property, but when I use "Publish" button from VS2019 it behaves like there is no profile and it seems reasonable, since it has no information about my shared profile.

I can't find any information on how VS2019 actually resolves publishing profiles while publishing from VS itself, so I've tried different things:

1. Creating symbolic link to Profile.pubxml from Solution1\WebProject1\Properties\PublishProfiles
2. "Add Existing Item"(Add file as Link) to the project

Seems that it only works when there is Profile.pubxml file inside Solution1(2)\WebProject1(2)\Properties\PublishProfiles folder.

Any other ideas on how to make it work? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Referencing shared publishing profile in Visual Studio 2019

**Actually**, it is designed by that. When you click **Publish** button, it will find the `xxx.pubxml` file under `project folder\Properties\PublishProfiles` and if the file does not exist under that path, VS will ask you to create a new file which is what happened to you.

**Suggestion**

**So it is impossible to do other operation** and you should put the file under `project folder\Properties\PublishProfiles` if you use **Publish** button to publish your project.

**In addition**, if you still want your idea, you could suggest a feature on [our User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).The Team will consider it carefully and hope they will give you a satisfactory reply.

Comment: Thanks, at least I don't have to spend my time trying to figure it out :)

Comment: Manually copying them every time the main repo is branched is aggravating to my flow, especially when I am just going for a quick experiment...